# How to get data from Indexed view?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, materialized-views

I have created Indexed view - let's call it PostBank. I keep there Id, CategoryName and UserId. How I get data from PostBank to controller? 
Thank You for Your time ;)

SQL command work perfectly, i tested. But I dont know is here possible to use Linq and how?

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what did you try, which errors did you get?

Comment: Yeah, Sry the question is Unclear. I edit it.

Comment: I updated my answer to your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference to a table. Just do

```
SELECT * (or Id, CategoryName, UserId) FROM Postbank
```

From any client, an indexed view is not different to a table or a view. you can use Linq against, you can do anything you can do against any other view. In fact, there really IS no difference from indexed view to "normal" view ITSELF (afaik, if i am wrong, please give advice, someone), the difference is just the index. You also have no difference (from the clients perspective) between an indexed and unindexed table. Here it is the same.

Comment: Yes 100% true answer. I noticed My problem wasn't in quering - problem was creating view. I had created wrong view, recreated it and fixed...
Thank You for Your help :)